# Joomla Virtuemart Credit Card Issues

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using the Joomla 1.5 and VM 1.1.9 V, as i am adding the Credit Card option from and working on it, throws the following error

```
Error : Failed Payment Processing. Technical Notes: The required transaction key is empty! The payment method settings must be reviewed. Error : Failed Payment Processing (ps_authorize)
```

Please help me out from this issues. What to configure next to make it workable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you haven't setup the transaction key, which means you didn't choose an online marchant service, I think this is a good tutorial to get your payment system working:

http://www.tonytechgeek.com/how-to-setup-credit-card-with-virtuemart-and-best-service-to-choose/